# Angular's Injectable Annotation: Can't resolve all parameters for HeroesComponent

Tags: angular, typescript

don't exactly know whether it makes a difference, but I created my angular project manually, with no usage of the angular CLI and i am using visual studio 2017 and typescript.

Currently I go through the Heroes tutorial of the angular guide (angular.io) and stopped with the Dependency Injection topic. When I create the Hero Service (manually), I got an typescript error telling my that the supplied parameters of the Injectable annotation does not match the required type arguments. It is possible to compile, but on runtime I got the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for HeroesComponent: (?).

So here is what i did:

The Hero Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root', }) export class HeroService {

    constructor() { }

    getHeroes(): Hero[] {
        return HEROES;
    }

}
```

And here is how i use the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';
import { HeroService } from '../hero-service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-heroes',
    templateUrl: '/App/HeroesComponentTemplate',
    styleUrls: ['../../../dist/styles/heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

    selectedHero: Hero;

    heroes = HEROES;

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
        console.log("onSelect hero");
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }
}
```

Here is my module defintion. Please keep in mind the original defintion did not include anything under providers, but now it's added without any effect.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms' ;

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component'

import { HeroService } from './hero-service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroesComponent,
        HeroDetailComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, 
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [
        HeroService
        ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So maybe there is anyone who can tell me if the problem is caused by not using the angular CLI and further on what is the right way to solve the issue without using the angular CLI?

I rely on angular 6.1.7 and typescript 3.0.3.

Source code added to github: [github repository](http://%20github.com/scs-tec/angular-hero-tutorial-vs)

Kind regards, 
Sebastian

Comment: Did you import your service in the heroes module ?

Comment: Can you add more information about the TypeScript error you've mentioned regarding the *supplied parameters of the Injectable annotation*? This makes it sound like you're not using Angular 6 but it's hard to tell at this stage, especially with your own manual project setup.

Comment: So i am using npm, so I did not exspected any version issues. The typescript error is: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: parameter type missmatch. Parameter 'options' should have type assignable to ((([providedIn: Object | "root"}) & Object) | (({providedIn: Object  | "root"}) & Object)  | .....but is has type '{providedIn: "root" }'.

Comment: angular version should be as exspected due to the javascript file of the angular compiler shows  @license Angular v6.1.7

Comment: What you have looks OK. At this stage, I suggest you upload your project to somewhere like GitHub so that we can run it ourselves and attempt to diagnose the issue.

Comment: here wo go: https://github.com/scs-tec/angular-hero-tutorial-vs

Comment: Has anyone checked out the Code ane could give Feedback if the Code Repository is helpful for finding a Solution regarding to that Problem? If it is Not the case I could provide my code in another format? Please give me an hint.

Comment: Did someone has checked out my code?